# No connections are available

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

Desktop machine operating on Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit Service Pack 1. Ethernet cable is plugged into the computer on one end, and into the WAN port of the wireless router on the other. There's another ethernet cable that connects the router and the modem, so I do have connection on all my mobile devices via Wi-Fi, but I can't get the LAN on the desktop to work.

The network adapter on it is the IC Plus IP100A 10/100 Fast Ethernet Adapter, and the Device Manager is saying that the driver is up to date.

When I run Network Diagnostics for the Local Area Connection I get the message that a network cable is unplugged.

Comment: Why would you plug it into the WAN port? It should be plugged into a LAN port.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem by keeping everything the same and replacing various parts, like the ethernet cable and network adapter

Comment: One of the ethernet cables (which is white, not that it matters) is plugged into a LAN port of the modem on one end, and the WAN port of the router on the other end. The other cable (which is blue) is plugged into a port named 1 (there are four of those) on the router on one end, and into the computer's port on the other.

Now, this used to work just fine, it gave Wi-Fi for my mobile devices, while I was able to connect on my desktop as well via ethernet. A few days ago, I gave the computer away for formatting, but I think the guy may have also changed the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply you have connected everything up wrong.

connect your modem to your router as follows:

`Modem -> ethernet cable -> router "WAN" socket`

Connect your PC to your router as follows

`PC (IC Plus 10/100/1000 adapter) -> ethernet cable -> router "1" socket`

You could, in theory, then connect other ethernet devices to router ports 2, 3 and 4 - another PC, laptop or games console if they are ethernet.

Comment: That's exactly the way they are connected.

Comment: Not according to your question... Your question shows that the PC is plugged into the router "WAN" port - which is incorrect. It is important that your modem is plugged into the router "WAN" port (often labeled "Internet"). If you are site they are correct then you may have a faulty cable. Make sure they're good, standard patch cables.